# Cannot convert string to char* for argument 1

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having an issue with my C++ code for converting a string of numbers in base b to another base n. My error is as follows:

> cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int base_to_decimal(char*, int)’

I am using g++ to compile, and I have been for a while, so I thought at first I knew what the issue was. It says that the method `base_to_decimal` accepts two arguments: one of type `char*` and one of type `int`. So all I should have to do to fix my issue is change the `char*` argument to a `string`, right?

Well, I looked, and the code for the function in question is:

```
int base_to_decimal(std::string input_base, int base)
```

So this method SHOULD be expecting a `string`, but for some reason when I pass in a `string`, it gets angry at me.

If someone could help me figure this out, that would be fantastic. I am using g++ 7.3.0, and running all this on Linux Mint 19.1.

(EDIT)

Main Method

[image]

Functions

[image]

Table

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you with code that's not shown. You obviously have a broken function declaration somewhere. You will have to find it, and fix it, yourself.

Comment: So we are telepathically supposed to know what the code is?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @OmidCompSCI **{{YES}}**. Evolve quickly, human. Your machines are catching up.

Comment: @user4581301 haha

Comment: I edited the post to include screenshots of the code. Error is at line 70.

Answer (score 0):

You've written a custom declaration on line 46 of your main:

```
 int base_to_decimal(char * input_base, int base)
```

But in the functions file where you've defined your function, you have:

```
int base_to_decimal(std::string input_base, int base)
```

This is why you should not write in-line declarations for external functions, but instead put the declarations in a header file. `#include` in the file where the function is later defined, ensures that the definition matches the declaration that the other files are expecting.  And likewise, it enforces that all those other files are trying to use the function the way it's actually coded.

Comment: Thank you. I will move all the declarations to a header file.